# How to send data from jsp to controller in spring using form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

How to send data from jsp to controller in spring using form ?

```
<form:form  action="${searchUrl}" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> search by ID </label> 
        <br>
           <input type="text" id="ticketId" placeholder=" Enter ticket ID ">                
    </div>

</form:form>
```

Could not able to get ticketId using this method

Comment: add name atribute along with input field and try <input type="text" id="ticketId" name="ticketId" placeholder=" Enter ticket ID ">

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare name attribute (`name="ticketId"`) and access the same on the controller. Like below.

JSP:

```
<input type="text" name="ticketId" id="ticketId" placeholder=" Enter ticket ID">
```

Controller:

```
@RequestParam(value = "ticketId", required = false) String ticketId
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is helpful to you, for me it is working fine.
If you want to use spring forms, make sure to follow the below steps :

**Step:1**.In the spring controller, you should return the bean object like below to respected JSP.

```
Class User {
       private String ticketId;
       // setter & getter
     }
      @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String init(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", "Please Enter Your Login Details");
                model.addAttribute("loginBean", new User()); 
            return "login";
        }
```

**Step:2** add a model attribute and add taglib in the JSP page.

```
        <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
        <form:form  action="${searchUrl}" method="post" 
         modelAttribute="loginBean">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label"> search by ID </label> 
                    <br>
                         <form:input type="text" id="ticketId" path = "ticketId"  
                          placeholder=" Enter ticket ID " />          
                </div>

            </form:form>
```

**Step : 3**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.Post)
        public String init(Model model,
                @ModelAttribute("user") User user,BindingResult 
          result) {
               sout("user"+user);
                return "home";
            }
```